# Apache error log format

Tags: apache, apache2.4

This is my errorlog format :

```
ErrorLogFormat "[%{u}t] [%-m:%l] [pid %P:tid %T] %7F: %E: [client\ %a] %M% , \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""
```

Sometime I have :

```
(70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client *(client IP)*:57108] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling)
```

But no script name/http request/file name = useless.

I just want something like {%script_name%} in the error (or the query if exist), for example with max excution timeout I don't have any request / filename.

Is it possible **without access log** ?

I have php-fpm 7.1 + apache 2.4 (no mod php)

Answer (score 1):

I also haven't found any simple ErrorLogFormat token for the request string. Instead I use mod_rewrite to set a variable which can then be used in ErrorLogFormat.

I use these settings:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule .* - [E=REQ:%{THE_REQUEST}]
ErrorLogFormat "[%{cu}t] [%a] \\n% \ Server:\ %V\\n% \ Request:\ %{REQ}e\\n% \ %M\\n% \ Referrer:\ %{Referer}i\\n% \ UserAgent:\ %{User-Agent}i\\n"
```

Comment: if you meant the word "Request:" to appear in the error log, it doesn't (Apache/2.4.56)

Comment: @NirO. works on Apache 2.4.52, haven't tested 2.4.56. "Request:" will only be shown if there is any request to show, i.e. if the RewriteRule worked. Have you enabled mod_rewrite?